# Preserving data integrity in a multi-step application

Tags: mysql, model, data-integrity

I'm currently working on a PHP web application with Symfony 2/Doctrine and MySQL as SGBD.

I have multiple steps (about 12) and at the end of a step, I store some data in my SGBD and I go to a next step, etc.

The user can return to a specific step with a 'go back' button. If he decides to do that, I need to update my stored data. For example, if a user is in step 6 and he returns to step 1, I need to clear some of my columns values.

My SQL model is light, 3 tables and I have a column state in one to keep the current step (step 1, step 2, etc). I don't know how to implement this.
Maybe it's a good idea to create stored procedures and call it before each save. In my mind, the stored procedure clean up my tables (perform an update) to restore at a given step.

Any ideas ?

Thankls

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a app design problem. If you are working with a framework my advice is to stay away from stored procedures and use your framework/DMS to interact with the database.

My suggestion would be to use a state machine. you need to:
1) Define all your steps
2) Define all possible transitions from one step to another

If you tell us more about the context on your problem we might be able to give you better advice. There are some great implementations for the state pattern for some frameworks

For symfony 2 i found these libraries:

https://github.com/yohang/Finite

https://github.com/winzou/StateMachineBundle